# How to randomly generate some id and return it until the end of program execution?

Tags: java, random

I'm not sure if I asked a proper question in the title, but will try to do it here

So, let's say I have some programm in Java, which is starting and ending

And I need to use some random generated id in this programm, BUT this id should not changing during programm execution, it should be generated again only with new start of programm execution

So, basically I need this - create a function, which will generate and return random id once the programm starts, and I want to have an access to this id from everywhere in my project, BUT everytime while I'm calling a function to get an id, it should return the same id, which was randomly generated, when the programm started

Is it possible to do so ?

Code, based on Mureinik answer (I want to use it as some kind of "dynamic constants generator"):

```
public class PseudoConstantBuilder {

    public static final int id;
    private String string;

    public PseudoConstantBuilder(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }

    static {
        Random random = new Random();
        id = random.nextInt();
    }

    public String generatePseudoConstant() {
        return String.format("%s_%s", string, id);
    }
```

and then using it somewhere like this:

```
public static final String activeCouponName = new PseudoConstantBuilder("activeCouponTest").generatePseudoConstant();
public static final String inactiveCouponName = new PseudoConstantBuilder("inactiveCouponTest").generatePseudoConstant();
```

Comment: Create it as one of the first things you do in your main object and store it in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to store it in a `static` variable, and initialize it in a `static` block when the program starts:

```java
public class IDStore {
    public static final int id;
    static {
        Random random = new Random();
        id = random.nextInt();
    }
}
```

And then access `IDStore.id` from wherever you need it.

Comment: `public static final int id = new Random().nextInt();` would do much the same, no need for the static initializer.

Comment: @Mureinik I updated the question with a code, based on your answer, can you please take a look and tell me will it work as expected ?

Comment: @Wonderio619 looks like it would do the right thing to me, but Andy's suggestion would be much shorter

Answer (score 1):

You can use
UUID.randomUUID() to generate unique id then you can use ThreadLocal to store this id and you will be able to access it wherever you want in the execution.

Comment: downvoting because the question doesn't mention UUIDs?  also, why use `ThreadLocal`, OP says they want the same ID for the whole program, not just in one thread